# apk build file come with errors in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, jenkins

Here, I have built the `react native android` app using this documentation [Doc](http://www.ziniostech.com/continuous-integration-react-native-application-aws-jenkins-bitbucketandroid/)
in `jenkins` which was configured on `ubuntu 16.04` (in virtual machine).

Here is the build command which I used to build the react native app(android) in Jenkins

`cd $WORKSPACE && chmod -R 777 ./android && cd ./android && npm install && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleDebug`

The build process end successfully creating an `apk` file in the following path 
`build_release_v1/ws/android/app/build/outputs/apk/`

**Note** `build_release_v1` is the jenkins project name and `ws` is for the workspace of it.

Though the `apk` is created it comes up with following errors

[image]

What may be the case ....please help me with this ...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you want a debug build (since you are using `assembleDebug`), React Native generates an APK that expects to have a connection to the bundle server (it does the same as `react-native run-android`). My guess is that you want to test the app without the bundler, so you have two options: either run `assembleRelease` instead (have a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-the-release-apk) for more details) or manually create the bundled JavaScript code and then create the APK. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961021/2628463) for details.